# Breaking a very large matrix, not process-able in r, into smaller process-able matrices

Tags: r, algorithm, matrix

I know that maximum limit of a vector length in r is `2^31 - 1`. So if I'm working with a matrix with 'k' rows, the largest dimension of a matrix I can get is `k x (2^31 - 1)/k`.

If, I have to generate combinations of certain number, 'r' from a vector of length, 'n', I can do this by `combn(n, r)` and get the number of combinations as `choose(n, r)`. The dimension of matrix generated by `combn(n,r)` is `r x choose(n, r)`. Now, given the data-set I'm working with, this number always exceeds the largest process-able matrix of dimension, `k x (2^31 - 1)/k`, as discussed above.

Now I need help in breaking down the `combn(n,r)` into different matrices and store in different variables every time the dimension, `r x (2^31 - 1)/r` is reached.

Can someone help me with this or with any other way to get over this problem.

TIA!

Comment: Have you tried the `bigmemory` package? I can't say for this particular example, but it handles large data well.

Comment: Can you offer some brief details about what problem you are actually trying to solve with this? The right algorithm can often reduce these kinds of problems to ones with much smaller memory/time requirements.

Comment: Hi, I tried, `as.big.matrix(combn(100,50))` and got the error `Error in vector("list", count) : vector size specified is too large`, so think we still look at the similar problem

Comment: @Marius I'll tell you what I'm trying to do with this part, I have a dataframe `df`, say with 'n' number of rows, each identified with a specific ID. We have built in a model, wherein we get the output as one of the combinations of `combn(n,r)`, which best suits our model, out off all the combinations. This output obviously contains 'r' rows out of 'n' in `df` dataframe. I think i'm clear at what I'm trying to convey. If, not let me know where you need clarity. Thanks.